# Estou com problemas com undefined index

Tags: php

```
 <?php 
$con = "";

function Conectar(){
$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$senha = "usbw";
$banco = "localcar";
$GLOBALS['con'] = new mysqli($servidor,$usuario,$senha,$banco);
}

//chamamos a função aqui para toda vez que fizermos include a conexão ser feita automaticamente..
Conectar();

function CadastrarCliente($nome,$cnh,$endereco){

    //comando da linguagem sql (do banco de dados mysql) para inserção de dados na tabela cliente
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (null,"'.$nome.'","'.$cnh.'","'.$endereco.'")';

    $res = $GLOBALS['con']->query($sql);
        if($res){
        //caso o comando seja executado sem problema, exibimos a mensagem abaixo
            alert("Cliente Cadastrado");
        }
}
function CadastrarVeiculo($placa,$modelo,$cor,$ano,$qntd_passageiro){

    //comando da linguagem sql (do banco de dados mysql) para inserção de dados na tabela veiculo
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO veiculo VALUES (null,"'.$placa.'","'.$modelo.'","'.$cor.'","'.$ano.'","'.$qntd_passageiro.'")';

    $res = $GLOBALS['con']->query($sql);
        if($res){
        //caso o comando seja executado sem problema, exibimos a mensagem abaixo
            alert("Veiculo Cadastrado");
        }
}
function alert($msg){
    echo '<script> alert("'.$msg.'");</script>';
}
function MostrarCliente(){
    //comando para listar todas os clientes
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM cliente LIMIT 0,4';
    //executando comando no banco
    $resultado = $GLOBALS['con']->query($sql);
    //verificando se existem clientes cadastrados
    if($resultado->num_rows > 0){
        //enquanto houver clientes, iremos mostrar
        while($cliente = $resultado->fetch_array()){
            //como será exibido (codigo html embutido)
            echo '<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                      <p>Nome: '.$cliente['nome'].'</p>
                      <p>CNH: '.$cliente['cnh'].'</p>
                      <p>Endereco: '.$cliente['endereco'].'</p>
                    </div> 
                  </div>';
        }
    }else{
        //nao tem Clientes
    }
}
function MostrarVeiculo(){
    //comando para listar todos os veiculos
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM veiculo LIMIT 0,4';
    //executando comando no banco
    $resultado = $GLOBALS['con']->query($sql);
    //verificando se existem veiculos cadastrados
    if($resultado->num_rows > 0){
        //enquanto houver veiculos, iremos mostrar
        while($veiculo = $resultado->fetch_array()){
            //como será exibido (codigo html embutido)
            echo '<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                      <p>Placa: '.$veiculo['placa'].'</p>
                      <p>Modelo: '.$veiculo['modelo'].'</p>
                      <p>Cor: '.$veiculo['cor'].'</p>
                      <p>Ano: '.$veiculo['ano'].'</p>
                      <p>Quantidade de Passageiros: '.$veiculo['qntd_passageiro'].'</p>
                    </div> 
                  </div>';
        }
    }else{
        //nao tem Veiculos
    }
}
?>
```

`

```
<?php 
include("funcoes.php");
if($_POST){
    CadastrarCliente($_POST['id'], $_POST['nome'],$_POST['cnh'],$_POST['endereco']);
CadastrarVeiculo($_POST['placa'],$_POST['modelo'],$_POST['cor'],$_POST['ano'],$_POST['qntd_passageiro']);
}
?>
<link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/scripts.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cliente').click(function(){
      $('#formCliente').slideToggle();
    });
    $('#veiculo').click(function(){
      $('#formVeiculo').slideToggle();
    });
    $('#formCliente').hide();
    $('#formVeiculo').hide();
  });
</script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">

      <li class="btn btn-success" id="cliente">
        Cadastrar Cliente
      </li>

      <li class="btn btn-success" id="veiculo">
        Cadastrar Veiculo
      </li>

    </div>
<div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <form action="index.php" method="post" id="formCliente">
          <p>
              <label for="">Nome</label><br>
              <input type="text" name="nome">
          </p>
          <p>
              <label for="">CNH</label><br>
              <input type="text" name="cnh">
          </p>
          <p>
              <label for="">Endereço</label><br> 
              <input type="text" name="endereco">
          </p>
          <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
          </p>
          </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <form action="index.php" method="post" id="formVeiculo">
              <p>
                  <label for="">Placa</label><br>
                  <input type="text" name="placa">
              </p>
              <p>
                  <label for="">Modelo</label><br>
                  <input type="text" name="modelo">
              </p>
              <p>
                  <label for="">Cor</label><br> 
                  <input type="text" name="cor">
              </p>
              <p>
                  <label for="">Ano</label><br> 
                  <input type="text" name="ano">
              </p>
              <p>
                  <label for="">Quantidade de Passageiros</label><br> 
                  <input type="text" name="qntd_passageiro">
              </p>
              <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
              </p>
          </form>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`

O que foi modificado com ajuda do Francisco.

```
    if($_POST)
{
    if(isset($_POST['nome']))
        CadastrarCliente($_POST['nome'],$_POST['cnh'],$_POST['endereco']);
    else if (isset($_POST['placa']))
        CadastrarVeiculo($_POST['placa'],$_POST['modelo'],$_POST['cor'],$_POST['ano'],$_POST['qntd_passageiro']);
}
```

Sou aluno de um curso onde tenho como exercício desenvolver um pequeno sistema de locação de veículos onde nele devo cadastrar dados do veículo e cliente, as funções estão todas certas e já consigo exibir as informações na página do usuário também, fiz 4 funções uma para cadastrar cliente, para veículo, uma para exibir as informações do cliente e outra para as do veículo, usei também dois formulários para mandar pra mesma pág usando method post.

provavelmente estou errando nessa primeira tag php:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Complementando...

Eu consigo cadastrar cliente só que cadastra o veiculo junto

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloca o código na pergunta e não uma imagem pf.

Comment: Poderia postar o código? Fica difícil ajudar com [imagens](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485)

Comment: Paulo, coloca o código na pergunta que nós ajudamos a formatar.

Comment: postei o código da função também

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está requerindo variáveis do `$_POST` sem antes instancia-las.

Por exemplo:

Você criou seu formulário e fez o envio das informações pelo método `$_POST` para a página `index.php`, ou seja, você só podera utilizar essas variáveis depois que o formulário for validado. E no seu caso, não é o que você está fazendo(linha 7). Você está pedindo as variáveis antes de ter criado(validado o formulário).

Jeito certo:

```
if($_POST)
{
    if(isset($_POST['id']))
        CadastrarCliente($_POST['id'], $_POST['nome'],$_POST['cnh'],$_POST['endereco']);
    else if (isset($_POST['placa']))
        CadastrarVeiculo($_POST['placa'],$_POST['modelo'],$_POST['cor'],$_POST['ano'],$_POST['qntd_passageiro']);
}
```

Comment: postei os códigos agora

Comment: Acredito que agora o erro não seja o mesmo, já que você editou o `if ($_POST)`.

Comment: modifiquei a foto, quero que quando eu cadastro um não modifique o outro ou não cadastra os dois juntos como está acontecendo no momento.

Comment: Recomendo que você crie um outro php, do qual só executa os comandos e já retorna para o `index.php`, é mais fácil e mais pratico. Já se deseja continuar com sua ideia de fazer tudo junto, vou editar minha resposta.

Comment: Pronto, veja se funciona agora.

Comment: Continuo conseguindo cadastrar só o segundo, mesmo assim obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: bom consegui, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Pelo que você está dizendo, parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.